# Finding an expression of the matrix $A^{-1}$ where $A^2−2 A−3 I =0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Suppose that A is an n×n matrix satisfying $A^2−2 A−3 I =0$ .Give an expression for $A^{−1}$ in terms of A and the identity matrix I.

I have never done this type of matrix question, so it would be extremely helpful if you can give me some **hints**.

The way I have thought about doing it is as follows:

$$A^2-2A=3I \implies A(A-2)=3I$$

$$A^{-1}A(A-2)=3IA^{-1}$$

$$\frac{1}{3}I(A-2)=A^{-1} I$$

If my working to this point is correct, I have no idea how to remove I from the right hand side of the equation which will help me to complete writing the expression in terms of A.

Comment: It is correct, $A^{-1}I=A^{-1}.$ Since $I$ is an Identity matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A^{-1} I$ is just $A^{-1}$, so your equation actually reads $$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{3}(A-2I).$$

Comment: I think you missed the I.

Comment: @M.S.E Yes $A-2$ should be $A-2I$ here

Answer (score 1):

It should be:
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{3} (A-2I)$$